# Foursquare API not returning public venue photos in userless API call?

Tags: foursquare, photos

I am making the following request as a userless API call:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/xxx123yyy/photos?v=20120321&group=venue
```

but the response I am getting shows a 0 count of items:

```
"response":  {
    "photos":  {
      "count": 0,
      "items":  []
    }
```

I can go to the same venue from the Foursquare webpage (without being logged in) and see the publicly listed photos there. If I try another venue, I get the expected response with same photo items as visible from web. What could be specific to this venue that is preventing the expected response?

Comment: secondary to my issue above, now - same as Jon P. - I am also receiving the 401 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this started happening earlier today, too.  The `venues/` endpoint appears to want an **oauth_token**, effectively breaking userless calls.

```
{"meta":{"code":401,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing oauth_token. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}
```

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that too. The Venues API was working perfectly well yesterday, but now it's broken, i.e. it requires OAuth authentication for the venues/ endpoint.
Anyone has an idea what's going on? Is this a new FS API bug?

Comment: It was a bug.  They just rolled back the bad publish.  (See https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI/statuses/235125486798372864)

Answer (score 0):

To get Photos using venue ID access Token is required...

If you want all non-friend's public photos
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{Vanue ID which you manage}/photos?group=venue&oauth_token={Your Access Tiken}&v={Current Data in yyyyMMdd format}

If you want all public photos
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{Vanue ID which you manage}/photos?&oauth_token={Your Access Tiken}&v={Current Data in yyyyMMdd format}